# pyspark: sparse vectors to scipy sparse matrix

Tags: apache-spark, scipy, pyspark, tf-idf

I have a spark dataframe with a column of short sentences, and a column with a categorical variable. I'd like to perform `tf-idf` on the sentences, `one-hot-encoding` on the categorical variable and then output it to a sparse matrix on my driver once it's much smaller in size (for a scikit-learn model).

What is the best way to get the data out of spark in sparse form? It seems like there is only a `toArray()` method on sparse vectors, which outputs `numpy` arrays. However, the docs do say that scipy sparse arrays [can be used in the place of spark sparse arrays.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector)

Keep in mind also that the tf_idf values are in fact a column of sparse arrays. Ideally it would be nice to get all these features into one large sparse matrix.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One possible solution can be expressed as follows:

- convert features to `RDD` and extract vectors:

  ```
  from pyspark.ml.linalg import SparseVector
  from operator import attrgetter

  df = sc.parallelize([
      (SparseVector(3, [0, 2], [1.0, 3.0]), ),
      (SparseVector(3, [1], [4.0]), )
  ]).toDF(["features"])

  features = df.rdd.map(attrgetter("features"))
  ```
- add row indices:

  ```
  indexed_features = features.zipWithIndex()
  ```
- flatten to RDD of tuples `(i, j, value)`:

  ```
  def explode(row):
      vec, i = row
      for j, v in zip(vec.indices, vec.values):
          yield i, j, v

  entries = indexed_features.flatMap(explode)
  ```
- collect and reshape:

  ```
  row_indices, col_indices, data = zip(*entries.collect())
  ```
- compute shape:

  ```
  shape = (
      df.count(),
      df.rdd.map(attrgetter("features")).first().size
  )
  ```
- create sparse matrix:

  ```
  from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

  mat = csr_matrix((data, (row_indices, col_indices)), shape=shape)
  ```
- quick sanity check:

  ```
  mat.todense()
  ```

  With expected result:

  ```
  matrix([[ 1.,  0.,  3.],
          [ 0.,  4.,  0.]])
  ```

Another one:

- convert each row of `features` to matrix:

  ```
  import numpy as np

  def as_matrix(vec):
      data, indices = vec.values, vec.indices
      shape = 1, vec.size
      return csr_matrix((data, indices, np.array([0, vec.values.size])), shape)

  mats = features.map(as_matrix)
  ```
- and reduce with `vstack`:

  ```
  from scipy.sparse import vstack

  mat = mats.reduce(lambda x, y: vstack([x, y]))
  ```

  or `collect` and `vstack`

  ```
  mat = vstack(mats.collect())
  ```